# Android screen lock and firebase topic messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

App is subscribed to a topic and *most* notifications are received when app is in foreground or background. However if I lock the emulator, I don't get the notifications. Is this by design due to the nature of the topic messaging?

```
...
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topic")
...
```

Comment: Let me know if more background information or code is needed to help assess this.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the notification sent from our servers had both the *notification* and *data* payload. When the emulator screen was locked (background state) the *data* payload was not handled. In our case there was nothing in the *notification* payload of value so once the notification block was removed from the push notification our app wakes up and all gets handled by

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
       //do stuff with your message like show notification, etc
    }
```